# Cannot escape parameters inside single quotes on a JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, binding

I want to make a query like this (note it contains some postgis functions) via JDBC:

```
SELECT id, name, ST_Y(location::geometry) as latitude, ST_X(location::geometry) as longitude, category_group, category 
FROM pois 
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-5.8340534 43.3581991)'), 1000000);
```

so I parametrized the query to:

```
SELECT id, name, ST_Y(location::geometry) as latitude, ST_X(location::geometry) as longitude, category_group, category 
FROM pois 
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(? ?)'), ?);
```

The problem is that when executing the preparedStament it can't find the first 2 parameters, because they are inside single quotes, so it gives an error.

I also tried to escape the single quotes with \' without success:

```
SELECT id, name, ST_Y(location::geometry) as latitude, ST_X(location::geometry) as longitude, category_group, category 
FROM pois 
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText(\'SRID=4326;POINT(? ?)\'), ?);
```

For now, as a workaround, I'm not binding the parameters, just appending the query string with them, but that's susceptible to SQL Injection, so I just want to know if there is any way to escape that sentence to make parameter binding work.

Comment: What error it gives ?

Comment: @NinadPingale Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:51)

Comment: Add that to your question, don't put extra information in comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asking myself, I'm using string concat:

```
"SELECT id, name, ST_Y(location::geometry) as latitude, ST_X(location::geometry) as longitude, category_group, category 
FROM pois 
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(' || ? || ' ' || ? || ')'), ?);"
```

Comment: And it is the only real solution, the behavior you described in your question is expected.

Answer (score 0):

As a naive answer....

You can assign the parameters before the query and later concatenate it with the Query
ex:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //don't forget to import java.util package
String par1 = scan.nextLine();
String par2 = scan.nextLine();
```

Later

```
String query = "SELECT id, name, ST_Y(location::geometry) as latitude, " + 
    "ST_X(location::geometry) as longitude, category_group, category " +
    "FROM pois " +
    "WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT("+par1+" "+par2+")'), ?)";
```

now pass this query to the Query Creation Statement

Comment: this is susceptible to SQL Injection, so it's not a good approach.